# Delete by DATE object filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In NodeJs, I need to delete records in MongoDB filtering by timezone (Date format).
In MongoDB, in a test record, I have:

```
"timestamp" : ISODate("2019-05-13T14:42:57.932+0000")
```

in the source code, I run the following query, passing a Date object as filter parameter for the delete command:

```
{timestamp: Mon May 13 2019 14:43:42 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)}
```

If I write in string format the filter above (contained in the findParams parameter), I have the following:

```
JSON.stringify(findParams)
'{"timestamp":"2019-05-13T12:43:42.877Z"}'
```

The result is that the record is not deleted on the db. Where is the error?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Code used to delete records in MongoDB:

```
 ​export​ ​async​ ​function​ ​deleteManyPromise​( 
 ​  ​collectionName​: ​string​, 
 ​  ​findParams​: ​Document​, 
 ​  ​proxy​: ​MongoObject​ ​=​ ​_fbMarkMongoProxy 
 ​)​ ​{ 
 ​  ​const​ ​existsCollection​ ​=​ ​await​ ​checkCollectionExists​(​collectionName​)​; 
 ​  ​if​ ​(​existsCollection​)​ ​{ 
 ​    ​try​ ​{ 
 ​      ​if​ ​(​!​proxy​.​connectedDb​)​ ​{ 
 ​        ​await​ ​proxy​.​connect​(​)​; 
 ​      ​} 
 ​      
  
 ​      ​const​ ​mongoDb​ ​=​ ​proxy​.​connectedDb​; 
  
 ​      ​const​ ​result​ ​=​ ​await​ ​mongoDb​! 
 ​        ​.​collection​(​collectionName​) 
 ​        ​.​deleteMany​(​findParams​)​; 
 ​      ​
 ​      ​return​ ​result​; 
 ​    ​}​ ​catch​ ​(​error​)​ ​{ 
 ​      ​await​ ​closeAllDbConnections​(​)​; 
 ​      ​throw​ ​Error​(​`Error deleting collection ​${​collectionName​}​ - ​${​error​}​`​)​; 
 ​    ​} 
 ​  ​}​ ​else​ ​{ 
 ​    ​return​; 
 ​  ​} 
 ​}
```

Comment: Which delete method do you use, can you paste that entire code block or reproduce?

Comment: Now I'm no longer at the computer; I use the deleteMany() of the MongoClient's nodes mongo driver

Comment: `db.collection.deleteMany()` should return deleted documents count. If you don't see that operation has completed successfully, that is probably a matter of query formulation. When you reach your computer, please paste your `deleteMany` block

Comment: Yes, the point is that 0 records were deleted

Comment: Question updated with code used to delete.

Comment: And findParams?

Comment: I wrote it in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243038/discussion-between-semperlabs-and-user1).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the only solution that works for me to delete a record in MongoDB is to find a date by using the following filter (I start from a timestamp of type STRING; I have to search a timestamp of type DATE in MongoDB):

```
timestamp: new Date(record.timestamp + "Z")
```

and then, to insert a new record in MongoDB with timestamp of type DATE, starting from a timestamp of type STRING I have to write:

```
record.timestamp = new Date(new Date(record.timestamp + "Z").toISOString());
```